# Cannot resolve TargetProperty when using StoryBoard in WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, storyboard, windows-runtime

I am trying to set a storyboard in code behind, but an exception is thrown every time saying

"Cannot resolve TargetProperty (UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX) on specified object."

Here is my code:

```
Image img = new Image() { Source = image.Source, Name="image"+i.ToString()};
var pointedStoryboard = new Storyboard();
var doubleAnnimationX = new DoubleAnimation();
doubleAnnimationX.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
doubleAnnimationX.To = 2;
pointedStoryboard.Children.Add(doubleAnnimationX);
Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnnimationX, img);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnnimationX, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)");
```

I tried also

```
Storyboard.SetTargetName(doubleAnnimationX, "image" + i.ToString());
```

instead of

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnnimationX, img);
```

but it did work too , don't know exactly what to do , I would be so thankful if you help me ! 
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add a composite transform to your image first.

```
img.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();
```

Then you should be able to reference it.

Comment: Over four years since you first answered and you just fixed a problem I've been battling for hours. Thanks so much!